# Android - Gson - JsonObject to class object

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, android-volley

I got this JsonObject from  JsonObjectRequest (im using Volley). How can I cast to Object?

{

"objects":
           [

```
       {"name":"German","id":5,},
       {"name":"Cecilia","id":6,},
       {"name":"Melina","id":7,},
       {"name":"Karina","id":8,},
       {"name":"Marcos","id":9,}

      ]
```

}

public class Invitados {

```
private String name;
private int id;


public Invitados(){}
public Invitados(String name, int id){
 this.name=name;
 this.id=id;
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gson library (as you included in tags to this question) create Gson object and use its [fromJson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)() method

Comment: But i have ant Objects array. How can i use gson  to get individual data from 

"objects": [

       {"name":"German","id":5,},
       {"name":"Cecilia","id":6,},
       {"name":"Melina","id":7,},
       {"name":"Karina","id":8,},
       {"name":"Marcos","id":9,}

      ]

Comment: Use List<Invitados> : List<Invitados> list= gson.fromJson(json, List<Invitados>.class); You may also use Invitados[].class

Comment: Dawid C, thanks for the answer.

I’m using Invitados[].  I try to use List<Invitados>.class but I have an error "Cannot Select from parametrize type"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    Invitados inv = new Invitados(obj.get("name").getAsString(),obj.get("id").getAsInt());  
    //Doing something...
}
```

Comment: I like it. But this time i would like to use Gson to practice.